# Per-application sound balance in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio, mixer

I like the new volume mixer in Windows 7, but it lacks balance controls. I know of the master balance control in the device properties, but what I really want is control of stereo balance per application, so I can have one program panned left and the other panned right.

Is there a way to add balance controls to the Windows 7 volume mixer, or is there a third-party application out there that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

[IndieVolume](http://www.softpedia.com/reviews/windows/IndieVolume--Review-73694.shtml) should do the job.

> IndieVolume is a small utility extending Windows with functionality to allow applications to have totally separate volume, balance and mute audio settings.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.  Link only answers don't tell us *why* we should go with your solution.